# Select Items from List<T> in MVC 4 using Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Given a class

```
public class Person
{
    // Some general properties

    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
}

public class Hobby
{
    // Some properties e.g. Name, etc.
}

static List<Hobby> AllHobbies { get; }
```

Is it possible to create a view that allows the user to select his hobbies using model binding?

It would certainly be possible in the view to loop through `AllHobbies` and render an `<input type="checkbox" />` for each, then wire up the selected values by hand in the postback controller.  It seems that this should be doable with model binding, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, I would recommend you using editor templates.

Let's suppose that a hobby has a name and a boolean field indicating whether it was selected by the user:

```
public class Hobby
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller to feed the model into the view and process the form submission:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            Hobbies = new[]
            {
                new Hobby { Name = "hobby 1" },
                new Hobby { Name = "hobby 2", Selected = true },
                new Hobby { Name = "hobby 3" },
            }.ToList()
        };
        return View(person);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Person person)
    {
        var selectedHobbies = person
            .Hobbies
            .Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Name);
        string message = string.Join(",", selectedHobbies);
        return Content("Thank you for selecting: " + message);
    }
}
```

then a view containing the form allowing the user to select hobbies:

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <h2>Hobbies</h2>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Hobbies)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and a corresponding editor template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the `Hobbies` collection (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Hobby.cshtml` -> notice that the name and location of the template is important):

```
@model Hobby

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Selected, Model.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
</div>
```

For more advanced editing scenarios I would recommend you going through the Steven Sanderson's [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) on this topic.

Comment: +1, great info.  The `Hobby` class however does not (and should not) have a Boolean indicating whether a particular user has selected it from the perspective of the domain model (this is a simplified example of course).  Do I have to add a transient Boolean field to the object to support this, or is there another way to do the binding without that extra field?

Comment: No, your mistake is that you are passing a domain model to your view. This is wrong. You should define a view model. Inside this view model you will have a boolean `Selected` property which will allow you to work with the checkboxes inside the view and fetch the selected values by the user. Then you will map the result to your domain model to do whatever you need to do with it. Remember the most important rule in MVC: controller actions pass/take only view models to/from views. Not domain models. View models are classes that you specifically design to meet the requirements of the given view.

Comment: Can you recommend a pattern for efficiently (as in time spent coding and testing) mapping between the domain model and view model?  This is actually the first instance (though I do very little UI development) where there has been any difference between the two.

Comment: You can also derive your view model from your model directly and add the properties you need.

Comment: No, deriving the view model directly from the domain model is a very bad idea. Don't do this.