# Dynamically Add Rows when using Editor Templates and EditorFor in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Expanding on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984727/select-items-from-listt-in-mvc-4-using-model-binding), I'm using EditorFor to edit a list of objects of type (let's say) `Hobby`.

Now, I need to implement functionality to add editors for individual `Hobby` objects, so that the user can add additional hobbies.

I read [Steven Anderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/12/22/editing-a-variable-length-list-of-items-in-aspnet-mvc/) about how to do that in MVC 2.  However, he's rendering the individual Hobby instances using a loop and RenderPartial, rather than using EditorFor.  I understand his approach of making Ajax calls to render another partial view and inserting the view result into the DOM, but don't know how to apply the Ajax add in my case, with EditorFor.

His code:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
    Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
%>
```

My code is using EditorFor like this:

```
// Model is a List<Hobby>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllowedSurveys)
```

**How do I add an additional Hobby editor, given that the editor is implemented as an Editor Template rather than as a Partial View?**

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your editor template with a partial:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AllowedSurveys)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Hobby", item);
}
```

and inside the partial (`~/Views/controllerName/_Hobby.cshtml`):

```
@model Hobby
<div class="editorRow">
    @using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("AllowedSurveys")) 
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        ...
    }
</div>
```

The `Html.BeginCollectionItem` custom helper is used to generate names with Guids and allow for reordering and adding new items to the collection using javascript. You can download it from the [updated article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). The one you were reading was for ASP.NET MVC 1 and is obsolete.