# Can HTML hidden field hold complex types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

In in post back to server side MVC controller action, to maintain the data for a MVC model property that is not for user input, the following topic suggests to use hidden field on markup view page:

[MVC3 - Why are navigation properties null on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423267/mvc3-why-are-navigation-properties-null-on-postback)

But to me, such an hidden field works just for a primitive C# types like int, bool, string etc. But complex-type property such as user-defined class or collection of primitive types (like List) does not work with hidden field on post back to server. Is my thought correct?

In fact, I tried such a hidden field for complex type property and the post back model property is **null**. Server side session object or database re-query is a rescue to re-populate complex-type property on server post back. Is there some other way to keep data for complex-type model property between post back?

I appreciate your help.

**Update:**
The hidden field for complex-type property is not data sensitive, no need data security for it. What I need to use some way rather than database re-query or server-side session variable. So, instead of using the hidden property as complex type in my MVC model, I use a **string** property that is complex-type serialized. On post back, I deserialize that hidden property to feed data for another property. Any idea?

Comment: If the user is not updating it from the UI, why to get it from the client. You should read it from your db if needed. But to your question,if you want to send complex objects, it is possible as long as the input field names match with the view model property hierachy

Comment: Yes your thoughts are correct, you cannot use a hidden input for complex types (unless you were to create custom ModelBinders). But you should not be including hidden inputs anyway (which can be manipulated by malicious users) - just get the data again in the post method

Comment: You could use a JSON string as long as you encode it properly to be sent back.

Comment: Just create a JSON or custom representation and with Custom ModelBinder and/or dynamic/JObject you will be able to get those details.

Comment: @vishal sharma  Can you please give me some example of it?

Comment: You can convert Custom Object to JSON with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` , Set those string data in ViewBag and Set that viewbag in Hidden Field.

Comment: here goes one more way of doing it... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623889/MVC-Complex-Model-Postback-Bind-Field-to-JSON-stri